# Cheap flight via Java Query and Scraping

Tags: java, html, scrape

I'm making a Java app that goes to Southwest.com and searches for a particular flight 4 times a day. If it finds a cheap flight, it e-mails the user.

I need to know how to input the data on the Southwest.com homepage (i.e. that I want a flight from JFK to SFO on 7/24/2011), so that I can scrape the HTML from the results page to deliver the lowest price.

Any help on how you would query the site in Java would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not much yet. I can upload an app to Google App Engine, but what I really want is just a basic tutorial on how to use a program to enter text into a text field on a website.

Comment: [southwest.com Terms & Conditions](http://www.southwest.com/html/about-southwest/terms-and-conditions/index.html?int=GFOOTER-BOTTOM-TERMS) .. **Prohibited Activities** You may not copy, display, distribute, download, license, modify, publish, re-post, reproduce, reuse, sell, transmit, use to create a derivative work, or otherwise use the content of this site for public or commercial purposes without our express written permission.

Comment: Please don't ask questions like this here.

Comment: I think that's a little harsh and I think closing it's a little harsh too. There's nothing in that legal statement from Southwest that would prevent someone from writing such an app for his own use or as an exercise.

Answer (score 3):

Be forewarned, you are at the mercy of the whims of their site architect and designer. I know, I spent a year doing much the same thing for an online retailing enterprise.

Use HTTPUnit, it renders the page in memory and you can retrieve the text and urls you need to post things to the site. Make sure you save the content of their page for debugging and logging purposes.

Use the information you retrieve via HTTPUnit to build urls and Form objects to post back to their site.

Good Luck!

Comment: +1 for the warning. It's often close to impossible

Comment: It was one of the more painful tasks I've had to do. And you'd get everything lined up just right and they'd change the website. All the urls were suddenly different and none of my code worked. twitch, twitch... :)

Answer (score 1):

Look into HTTPRequests. Basically, the fields will be sent via GET or POST parameters.

The format of the parameters is usually like:

&param1=JFK&param2=somevalue...

With GET method, you can append the parameters to the end of the URL like this:
www.site.com?param1=JFD&param2=...

With POST, you have to send the params as a stream following the URL.

The Java class you can use is:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: The Southwest URL links directing to the results only work for, like, 10 minutes.